# What algorithm to use to predict customer count given past data?

Tags: prediction, algorithms

I want to predict the number of customers on an hourly basis in a store given its previous data regarding how many customers came in the store per hour. The prediction would look like something below:

[image]

The data which I have lists the number of customers per hour on a given date.

Furthermore, I also have customer count of current hour as well as consequently previous hours. What algorithm can I use to also make use of that in the prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quite probably have [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities):

- Intra-day patterns (visible in your picture)
- Intra-week patterns - weekdays and weekends will likely look very different
- Possibly also intra-year patterns, with differences between summer and winter

Thus, I would recommend you use a [forecasting](/questions/tagged/forecasting) algorithm that can deal with such multiple seasonalities. The best-known such models are the [bats](/questions/tagged/bats) and [tbats](/questions/tagged/tbats) models. Look at both tags' wikis to learn more, including pointers to R functions and the original JASA publication.